# Probability for the Quotient of two lognormal distributions (Analytical vs Monte Carlo)

Tags: probability, distributions, monte-carlo, lognormal-distribution

I am struggling on a problem for some time now and any help would be highly appreciated.

From an "easy" problem, known to have a closed-form solution, I find strange the existence of such a huge discrepancy with the results obtained through a Monte Carlo simulation.

I have

[image]  and [image]

As I only know the two below distributions, correlated with a factor [image] :

[image] and [image]

My main goal being to find the probability that L is exceeding a threshold Ltrigger both at maturity T and on a continuous basis (first-passage probability).

[image][image] >  [image]

I decided to rewrite the problem as

[image] > [image]
[image]

Indeed, X & Z are log-normally distributed, so log(X) and log (Z) are normally distributed, involving [image] being also normally distributed. Setting [image], we have [image] and [image]

Considering only the case at maturity only (in a first time), the probability can be either equal to

[image]
[image]

or, from Ito's lemma (or/and with the quotient/ratio rule) the result is already slightly different:

[image]
[image]
With [image] the normal cumulative distribution function

In this last version, the correlation coefficient disappear from the numerator and this is consistent from the fact that if a random variable V follows [image], then
blank">{0}&space;)&space;=&space;\Phi&space;(&space;\frac{v_{0}&space;-&space;\mu&space;}{&space;\sigma&space;}&space;)" title="\mathbb{P}( V < v_{0} ) = \Phi ( \frac{v_{0} - \mu }{ \sigma } )" /> and it appears that [image]

Finally, what is strange is that I obtain a better fit, when turning the sign of the standard deviations in the lastest analytical form i.e. for 
[image]
[image]

Below is an example of the results with three different correlation tried out (0, 1 and -1). The x-axis is the [image].

[image: Correlation = 0]
[image: Correlation = 1]
[image: Correlation = -1]

Please also note that I used the below set of data:

[image]

Definitely, the "opposite sign" model seems more suitable, but increasing for example [image] to 0.5% provide a probability to reach the trigger at maturity that tends to 0. This is not logical as increasing the growth rate of Z is supposed to increase Y, making L more likely to reach [image].

I think that already if someone have an explanation or could help with that, I would be able to adapt my formula to the first-hit model with the exponential adjustment.

Thank you very much,
Xyokube